# Google insights results are different via API and web interface

Tags: google-api, pagespeed

I have a problem with page speed measurments, for example:
via api
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=https://www.makeupforever.com/fr/fr-fr&strategy=mobile
  "SPEED": {
   "score": 33
  },
  "USABILITY": {
   "score": 97
  }

But if Im testing via user interface on
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.makeupforever.com%2Ffr%2Ffr-fr
And it has
[image]

My question is why results are different and how do I retrieve equal results in API and PageSpeed interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your request url to the actuall version:

https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v4/runPagespeed

see release notes:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/release_notes

Comment: Still not equal https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v4/runPagespeed?url=https://www.makeupforever.com/fr/fr-fr&strategy=mobile is *67* and https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.makeupforever.com%2Ffr%2Ffr-fr&tab=mobile is *39*

Comment: I am still experiencing this issue. Any ideas?